# What's the format of the OpenOffice dictionaries?

Tags: parsing, dictionary, spell-checking, file-format

Does anyone know what the format of the OpenOffice dictionary files are? As far as I can see there is one word per line, and some flags that presumably tells me something about the word.

Here's a couple of lines from the english dictionary as an example:

```
absoluteness/S
absorbency/SM
abstract/ShTVDPiGY
absurdness/S
```

And from the Norwegian dictionary, which is what I'll use:

```
flatorm/AEG
flatpresse/W
flatseng/ACEG
flatside/ACDEFGHJ
flatskjerm/A
```

What does for instance "/AEG" and "/S" mean? I assume each letter/flag has a certain meaning, so that tha A in "/AEG" means the same as the A in "/ACDEFGHJ".

I have googled all over the place, but I can't find any information.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

OO uses the [hunspell](http://hunspell.sourceforge.net/) engine for spell-checking. The stuff after the "/" is linked to data in the corresponding [affix file](http://pwet.fr/man/linux/fichiers_speciaux/hunspell).

Comment: Hi, Alex! Does hunspell engine allow to get nominal form of the word? For instance for word "running" -> "run" or for word "cats" -> "cat". I know that there is Porter Stemming Algorithm, but it is not working for language I need this functionality (but those languages has Open Office dictionaries)