# Dictionary File Structure of Open Spell-Checkers

Tags: dictionary, spell-checking, openoffice.org, libreoffice, hunspell

Is there any explanation docs or tutorials of the file structure of FreeDict, Aspell, Hunspell/OpenOffice Dictionaries especially concerning the switches at the end of each row in each `.dic` file? My guess is that the switches describe the semantic interpretation of the word whether it's a

- noun
- adjective
- adverb
- adverbial
- etc.

or any combination of the above. But I don't know how to match these to the switch characters.

I'm also curios about what the `.aff` file describes.

Answer (score 1):

[This](http://www.openoffice.org/lingucomponent/dictionary.html) looks like a good starting point, and the [downloads at this page](http://fmg-www.cs.ucla.edu/geoff/ispell-dictionaries.html#English-dicts) may have the format documentation you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Just a couple of links that might help you:

this is on sthackoverflow :
[What's the format of the OpenOffice dictionaries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3060301/whats-the-format-of-the-openoffice-dictionaries)

this second one is a good start

http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/freedict/index.php?title=Main_Page

hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

In Hunspell the tags you choose are arbitrary, they have no meaning other than that which you assign to them. You can choose from using letters, numbers (1-65535) and more.

The affix file describes many things, but is mainly concerned with how words are inflected.

For example:

```
$ test.dic
4
apple/a
banana/a
green/b
small/b

$ test.aff
SFX a Y 2 # Allow the following 2 suffixes to words with the "a" flag.
SFX a 0 s . # An "s" at the end for words ending in any letter (signified by the dot). "Apples" and "bananas". 
SFX a 0 s' . # "Apples'" and "bananas'".

SFX b Y 2
SFX b 0 er . # "Greener" and "smaller".
SFX b 0 est . # "Greenest" and "smallest".
```

[The manual](http://sourceforge.net/projects/hunspell/files/Hunspell/Documentation/) explains most of the things in detail. There are also test files one can look at.